# edit an environment to add to a new extra parameter

Tags: environments, counters, parameters

I'm trying to define a new  `\newenvironment` but I'm having some problems. I need an environment that uses a counter and uses an extra parameter to write some text.

I'm working with this environment:

```
\newenvironment{homeworkProblem}[1][-101010]{
\ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{#1}
\fi
\section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}
\setcounter{partCounter}{1}
\enterProblemHeader{homeworkProblemCounter}
```

This environment works with the following counters:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcounter{partCounter}
\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}
\setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{1}
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}{}\nobreak{}
```

And also with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{
\nobreak\extramarks{}{Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page}\nobreak{}
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)}{Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page}\nobreak{}
}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
 \newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)}{Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak{}
\stepcounter{#1}
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{#1}}{}\nobreak{}
}
```

I tried to edit with this environment to put an extra parameter, I want this parameter {#2} to appear in the line:

```
\section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}
```

And change it to:

```
\section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter} ( Book {#2} )}
```

I use the command `\section`, because I like how it looks. I tried to edit the code but it did not work

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure whether the `\setcounter` way will provide correct labels. Where is `\exitProblemHeader` used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example works, the issue is that when you define an environment (or a command) with a default argument (i.e., `\newenvironment{env}[2][1]{...}{...}`), the use is `\begin{env}[1]{2}...`.

Thus, if you define you environment as

```
\newenvironment{homeworkProblem}[2][-101010]{
\ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{#1}
\fi
\section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter} (book #2)}}{}
```

then you have to write

```
\begin{homeworkProblem}{a}
  test
\end{homeworkProblem}
```

to use the default value for the first argument, and

```
\begin{homeworkProblem}[3]{b}
  test
\end{homeworkProblem}
```

when you pass it explicitly.